# Distributed calculation on Cloud Foundry with help of auto-scaling

Tags: spring-boot, mapreduce, distributed-computing, cloud-foundry, autoscaling

I have some computation intensive and long-running task. It can easily be split into sub-tasks and also it would be kind of easy to aggregate the results later on. For example Map/Reduce would work well.

I have to solve this on Cloud Foundry and there I want to get advantage from autos-caling, that is creation of additional instances due to high CPU loads. Normally I use Spring boot for developing my cf apps.

Any ideas are welcome of how to divide&conquer in an elastic way on cf. It would be great to have as many instances created as cf would do, without needing to configure the amount of available application instances in the application. Also I need to trigger the creation of instances by loading the CPUs to provoke auto-scaling.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to solve this on Cloud Foundry

It sounds like you're on the right track here.  The main thing is that you need to write your app so that it can coexist with multiple instances of itself (or perhaps break it into a primary node that coordinates work and multiple worker apps).  However you architect the app, being able to scale up instances is critical.  You can then simply `cf scale` to add or remove nodes and increase capacity.

If you wanted to get clever, you could set up a pipeline to run your jobs.  Step one would be to scale up the worker nodes of your app, step two would be to schedule the work to run, step three would be to clean up and scale down your nodes.

I'm suggesting this because manual scaling is going to be the simplest path forward (please read on for why).

> and there I want to get advantage from autos-caling, that is creation of additional instances due to high CPU loads.

As to autoscaling, I think it's possible but I also think it's making the problem more complicated than it needs to be.  Auto scaling by CPU on Cloud Foundry is not as simple as it seems.  [The way Linux reports CPU usage, you can exceed 100%, it's 100% per CPU core](https://superuser.com/questions/174660/why-is-the-cpu-usage-reported-by-top-in-linux-over-100).  Pair this with the fact that you may not know how many CPU cores are on your Cells (like if you're using a public CF provider), the fact that the number of cores could change over time (if your provider changes hardware), and that makes it's difficult to know at what point you should scale your application.

If you must autoscale, I would suggest trying to autoscale on some other metric.  What metrics are available, will depend on the autoscaler tool you are using.  The best would be if you could have some custom metric, then you could use work queue length or something that's relevant to your application.  If custom metrics are not supported, you could always hack together your own autoscaler that does work with metrics relevant to your application (you can scale up and down by adjusting the instance cound of your app using the [CF API](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/280/apps/updating_an_app.html)).

You might also be able to hack together a solution based on the metrics that your autoscaler does provide.  For example, you could artificially inflate a metric that your autoscaler does support in proportion to the workload you need to process.

You could also just scale up when your work day starts and scale down at the end of the day.  It's not dynamic, but it simple and it will get you some efficiency improvements.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! The auto-scaling is handled by cloud foundry infrastructure itself, so I do not need to do that on my own. It happens automatically if the load is there. I could easily split my task into 100 sub-tasks. That would be OK, if there are 100 instances coming up. But it would overwhelm the infrastructure if there are only 2 instances available for me. So somehow I need to relate the breakdown into subtasks to the amount of workers available. But that amount of workers I do not really know in advance, only after creating some load.

Comment: Does your autoscaler support a range?  i.e. a min and max number of nodes.  That would at least give you some idea of how many nodes would be there.  If you truly want to embrace autoscaling though, you would just fire off as many tasks as you need and wait for the autoscaling to kick in.  It should scale up to its max, or the max needed for that workload and then back down.  If the platform doesn't have the capacity desired, that's an issue regardless of how you scale.

Comment: Since you're using Spring Boot already, you might want to check out Spring Cloud Data Flow and the associated Spring Stream & Spring Task projects.  I don't think they strictly answer your question, but they provide a lot of support to make running batch/task processing workloads easier & they run nicely on top of Cloud Foundry.

Comment: The autoscaler has a range of nodes configured, but I did not find a possibility to know that range within my application. I quickly checked Spring Cloud Data Flow, but I do not really know how that could help me with my problem...